# How do I get into the setting of PHP Inspection plugin?

Tags: php, plugins, phpstorm, settings

I have installed the [Php Inspection (EA Extended)](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7622-php-inspections-ea-extended-) plugin in PhpStorm.

Yet where can I change its settings?

I want see all its possible checks, enable, disable them, and I want to the severity of each check (from light warning to error).

Yet all I see in the settings is:

[image: Plugin settings but it's useless]

For example, php inspect currently complaints about:

```
EA Use::self
```

in my unit tests and wants to change

```
$this->assertEquals()
```

to

```
self::assertEquals()
```

yet I want to completly disable that check.

How can I do it?

Comment: @LazyOne You can post that one as an answer as wellt :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This plugin provides inspections, so they can be configured in the same place where other inspections are: `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Inspections | PHP | Php Inspections (EA Extended)`

[image]

For a quick access to the active inspection that generates some notice in your code you can definitely use Quick Fix menu: using it all the time:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a direct way to PHP Inspections' settings, yet when you press on

Alt + Enter

on the offending word, cursor on any letter of the `$this` keyword. You'll see:

```
[Ea Use self::] >
```

Pressing enter will apply the autofix. Yet it functions as a menu, meaning you can press right arrow then you'll see a list, and the first item is:

```
 Edit inspection profile setting
```

This will open the complete settings window:

[image: Settings window of PHP Inspections]

Here you can select and unselect checkboxes to enable or disable checks and you can set the severity on the right panel.

Also pertaining to your use case, the setting for:

```
Static method invocation via '->'
```

has an option to specifically disable only on phpunit, namely:

```
Except PHPUnit assertions
```

so you could leave it otherwise in tact.